# Editing img src style with variables based on specific resolutions

Tags: php, html, image, src

I am trying to do something I thought would be a lot simpler but I'm having issues.

The default header size on my webpage is 1500x500 and on lower resolutions (laptops) this 1500 is obviously a problem. I have a macro that needs this header resolution specifically though and that macro runs & was wrote at 1600x900 screen resolution.

So the thought process was this:

- Get screen resolution. (Done)
- Do an IF screen resolution for 1600x900 where it'll recognise when I have that resolution and do something, else, do something else. (done)
- Change image width/height in the if. (Problem)

So the actual doing something I'm having issues with.

```
<center>
    <?php
        session_start();
        if(isset($_SESSION['screen_width']) AND isset($_SESSION['screen_height']))
            {
                echo 'User resolution: ' . $_SESSION['screen_width'] . 'x' . $_SESSION['screen_height'];
            } 
            else 
            if(isset($_REQUEST['width']) AND isset($_REQUEST['height'])) 
            {
                echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?width="+screen.width+"&height="+screen.height;</script>';
            }
    ?>

    <?php if ($_SESSION['screen_width'] == 1600 && $_SESSION['screen_height'] == 900)
    {
         //Don't change style, this is a resolution we want precise width on
        $width1 = 500 +"px";
        $height1 = 50 +"px";
    }
    else
    {
          //Change style, any other resolution we go for 100%
        $width1 = 100 +"%";
        $height1 = 100 +"%";
    }
    ?>

  //This is the header/image in question. 
  src="https://i.imgur.com/rGEjK9e.png" style.width = width, style.height = 
  height1;>
    </center>

  //This is the old header image code.
 <center>
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/C4KSU7g.png" alt="" style="width:1500px;height:500px;”>
</center>
```

I have it echo'ing to show that my if works and that it knows my screen size, but I want to now make it change only 1 specific image width / height as a result of that IF.

I'm not really taught in this language.

Comment: It'd be better do it on the client-side using CSS Media queries. Is there some requirement that it should be done on server-side?

Comment: We do all our sites server-side. Wouldn't know where to begin with client-side and the idea being once this works it'll be used a script to be used on other sites too. 

I don't know if that would work client side with many clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working. Entire code:

```
    <center>
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['screen_width']) AND isset($_SESSION['screen_height']))
    {
        //echo 'User resolution: ' . $_SESSION['screen_width'] . 'x' . $_SESSION['screen_height'];
    }
    else if(isset($_REQUEST['width']) AND isset($_REQUEST['height'])) 
    {
        $_SESSION['screen_width'] = $_REQUEST['width'];
        $_SESSION['screen_height'] = $_REQUEST['height'];
        header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    } 
    else
    {
        //echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?width="+screen.width+"&height="+screen.height;</script>';
    }
?>

<?php if ($_SESSION['screen_width'] == 1600 && $_SESSION['screen_height'] == 900)
{
     //Don't change style, this is a resolution we want precise width on
    $width1 = "1500"."px";
    $height1 = "500"."px";
    //echo $width1;
    //echo $height1;
    //echo "Header won't change";
}
else
{
      //Change style, any other resolution we go for 100%
    $width1 = "100"."%";
    $height1 = "100"."%";
    //echo $width1;
    //echo $height1;
    //echo "Header will change";
}
$text = "<img src='https://i.imgur.com/rGEjK9e.png' style='width:$width1;height:200px></center>";

preg_match_all("/<img.*>/",$text,$out);
foreach($out as $t1)
{
    foreach($t1 as $img)
    {
        preg_match("/.*height:(.*?);width:(.*?);.*/",$img,$out2);
        $height = $out2[1];
        $width = $out2[2];
        $text = str_replace($out2[0],str_replace("<img","<img width='" . $width1 . "' height='" . $height1 . "'",$out2[0]),$text);
    }
}
echo $text;
?>
```

Fixed a few things and found this str_replace. Set your image links in question as a text and put it through this checker, echo the text and it'll work somehow. Not sure why I couldn't set height / width myself but it works so i'm not complaining.

My variables weren't adding the "px" and "%" from before, + doesn't work apparently, you have to use ., ie "100"."px"

Now the header is responsive for every resolution except 1600x900 which is ideal. On chrome, anyway. A quick look at edge and it seems to not recognise resolution. Open to any improvements of this code.